# Codeigniter Google maps api

Tags: codeigniter, maps

I just tested the google maps api to codeigniter but with an error that I did not understand.
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: map

the code is from here

http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the "googlemaps" library?

Comment: class Map extends CI_Controller 
{
 function index()
 {
  $this->load->library('googlemaps');
  $config['center'] = '35.825795, 10.607212';
  $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
  $config['directions'] = TRUE;
  $config['directionsStart'] = 'Sousse Railway';
  $config['directionsEnd'] = 'Sousse Sud';
  $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv';
  $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
  $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
  $this->load->view('maps', $data);
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET["w1"]) && isset($_GET["w2"]))
{
    $config['center'] = $lat = $_GET["w1"].','.$lng = $_GET["w2"];
    $marker = array();        
    $marker['position'] = $lat = $_GET["w1"].','.$lng = $_GET["w2"];
    $latlng = $_GET["w1"].','.$_GET["w2"];
    $request = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=.$latlng.&key=AIzaSyAOAR94QMB9YdE8RXHG-8NE28cz6wdUw2I');
    $json = json_decode($request, true);                                            
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = implode("|", $json);
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);             
}
```